# Autolayout "conflicting constraints"

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've created a custom `UIView` that I use modally to display a `UIToolbar` and `UIPickerView`. I'm trying to make it very reusable, so I'm creating all of the UI in code, including setting constraints.

Here's the method body I use to set the view up to be added to another view, and then to animate the controls up onto the view from the bottom.

My view hierarchy is as follows:

```
"Owner" view (view to which this view is added):<br>
    |-->"Background" view (set to the full size of "Owner", but mainly used as a dimmed background)<br>
        |-->"Container" view (view which holds the toolbar and picker)
            |--> Toolbar
            |--> Picker
```

Here's the code I use to set up the UI:

```
- (void)prepareForView:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *containerView       = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [containerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.containerView          = containerView;

    UIPickerView *picker        = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 162.0f)];
    [picker setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.picker                 = picker;

    UIToolbar *toolbar          = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
    [toolbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    UIBarButtonItem *done       = ...;
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace  = ...;
    UIBarButtonItem *cancel     = ...;
    toolbar.items               = @[done, flexSpace, cancel];

    [containerView addSubview:picker];
    [containerView addSubview:toolbar];

    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[picker]|"                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline  metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(picker)]];
    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[toolbar]|"                          options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline  metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toolbar)]];
    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[toolbar(==44)][picker(==162)]|"   options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading   metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toolbar, picker)]];

    [containerView layoutIfNeeded];

    [self addSubview:containerView];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[containerView]|"                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline  metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)]];
    self.containerTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:self.frame.size.height];
    [self addConstraint:self.containerTop];

    [self layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Basically, I want `containerView` to be sized according to its contents (which should be a static 206 points). Then, I set a vertical space constraint between its top and the top of its superview (which is `self`). Later, I animate changing that so that the toolbar and picker "slide up" onto the screen.

Here's the animation code (the error is always triggered BEFORE this point):

```
// Add the view as a subview
[view addSubview:self];

// Setup view for display (here's what triggers the message)
[self prepareForView:view];

// Animate into view
[UIView animateWithDuration:animated?0.4f:0.0f
                 animations:^{
                     self.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // Now, slide the container view in from the bottom of the screen
                     self.containerTop.constant = self.frame.size.height - self.containerView.frame.size.height;
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:animated?0.4f:0.0f
                                      animations:^{
                                          [self layoutIfNeeded];
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          if (postDisplay != nil) {
                                              postDisplay();
                                          }
                                      }
                      ];
                 }
 ];
```

This is currently displaying correctly on all simulators and devices in testing, but I hate having warnings/errors, and I'm worried that this might **NOT** work as desired at some point.

Here's the actual error message that's displayed (I'm pretty sure this is exactly the same error every time):

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170283430 V:|-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x137590850]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170382b10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170283480 V:[UIToolbar:0x137590850(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174084ba0 V:[UIToolbar:0x137590850]-(0)-[UIPickerView:0x137586100]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174081fe0 V:[UIPickerView:0x137586100(162)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409bbc0 V:[UIPickerView:0x137586100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170382b10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174095b80 V:[UIView:0x170382b10(736)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174084ba0 V:[UIToolbar:0x137590850]-(0)-[UIPickerView:0x137586100]>
```

What I don't understand is that all of the constraints ARE expected, and then the displayed UI is what I intend. When I inspect the view's layout with `po [self.containerView recursiveDescription]` in the debugger, I see the frames being exactly what I think they ought to be. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The "Container" view appears to have a height of 736 from the line below:
`<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174095b80 V:[UIView:0x170382b10(736)]>`

You have laid out the view as below:
------ Top of UIView ------- (y = 0)
- 0 Space -
UIToolBar (y = 0 to y = 44)
- 0 Space -
UIPickerView (y = 44 to y = 206) ***
- 0 Space -
------ Bottom of UIView ----- (y = 736)

*** This is where the conflict arrises. This can't be 0 space away from the bottom of the UIView with all of the other constraints set the way that they are or the height of the UIView cannot be what it is with all of the other constraints.

EDIT:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[containerView]|"                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView)]];
```

When you use "|" within a the visualFormat for a constraint this is the parent view. Within this line you are saying you want the parent view to 0 space to the top of the [containerView] and also 0 space from the bottom of the [containerView]. This makes the container view the same height as the parent.

Edit #2:
Look at the following. I believe this is close to what you are trying to accomplish.

```
[containerView addSubview:picker];
[containerView addSubview:toolbar];
[self addSubview:containerView];

// Height & Width for containerView
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[containerView(%f)]", containerView.frame.size.height] options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"containerView":containerView}]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[containerView(%f)]", containerView.frame.size.width] options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"containerView":containerView}]];

// Height & Width for picker
[picker addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[picker(%f)]", picker.frame.size.height] options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"picker":picker}]];
[picker addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[picker(%f)]", picker.frame.size.width] options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"picker":picker}]];

// Height & Width for toolbar
[toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[toolbar(%f)]", toolbar.frame.size.height] options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"toolbar":toolbar}]];
[toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[toolbar(%f)]", toolbar.frame.size.width] options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"toolbar":toolbar}]];

// Vertical Positioning of picker & toolbar in containerView
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[picker]" options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"picker":picker}]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[toolbar]-0-|" options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"toolbar":toolbar}]];

// Horizontal Positioning of picker & toolbar in containerView
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:picker attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:toolbar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

// Center containerView (X/Y) in parent (self)
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Edit #3: Using 'views' and 'metrics' dictionaries.

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"containerView":containerView, @"picker":picker, @"toolbar":toolbar};
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"hCV":containerView.frame.size.height,
                          @"wCV":containerView.frame.size.width,
                          @"hP":picker.frame.size.height,
                          @"wP":picker.frame.size.width,
                          @"hT":toolbar.frame.size.height,
                          @"wT":toolbar.frame.size.width};

[containerView addSubview:picker];
[containerView addSubview:toolbar];
[self addSubview:containerView];

// Height & Width for containerView
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[containerView(hCV)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[containerView(wCV)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

// Height & Width for picker
[picker addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[picker(hP)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[picker addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[picker(wP)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

// Height & Width for toolbar
[toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[toolbar(hT)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[toolbar(wT)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

// Vertical Positioning of picker & toolbar in containerView
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[picker]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[toolbar]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

// Horizontal Positioning of picker & toolbar in containerView
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:picker attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:toolbar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

// Center containerView (X/Y) in parent (self)
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: Ok, but why does it do that? I see where it gets the 736 from the initial frame I set, but isn't that just a starting point? Isn't that "fixed" when I call `[self.containerView layoutIfNeeded]`? How would I go about "fixing" this issue? Maybe just `alloc] init]` the view without a frame?

Comment: I tried the `alloc] init]` (which I understand to essentially be `alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`), and it came up with the same error, except the (736) was now (0). So, I guess I don't understand why there's a constraint associated with the height of `self.containerView` at all. Where is that coming from and how do I remove it?

Comment: I really appreciate the help. In your "edit" (#1), I agree that it's setting the "edge gaps" to zero, but without the "V:|", it's in the horizontal, right?

Comment: FWIW, I rearranged the code a little bit and I noticed that I was calling `[containerView layoutIfNeeded]` followed almost immediately  by `[self layoutIfNeeded]`. I removed the `[containerView layoutIfNeeded]` and the error went away. Not sure I get it completely, but I'll take it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: `@"V:"` precedes vertical constraints. `@"H:"` precedes horizontal constraints. `|` anywhere in the string denotes the parent view.

Comment: You shouldn't be using stringWithFormat: in your format strings -- just pass the literal string.

Comment: @egarlock Yes, "|" means the parent view, but it only related to either horizontal or vertical for one formatted string. Thus, when you don't specify "V:" or "H:", it assumes horizontal.

Comment: mbm29414 - I see what you are saying. I don't know why you would not want to speficy.

@rdelmar Why should you not use stringWithFormat?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed part of that line. It's ok to do it the way you are (I assume it's ok, I've never seen people do it this way, as opposed to using the metrics dictionary to pass in a variable).

Comment: mbm29414 - I just found this blog post and it has made things clearer for me so I thought I would share it. http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/